# fetching bandwidth from rabbitmq queues

Tags: java, python, rabbitmq

This should be trivial.. but I couldn't find a quick guide to do it.. nor can I find it on the rabbitmq, I want to understand what's the incoming outgoing bytes rate for a specific queue (and not msgs/s), is that possible? console/command line would be lovely,

Thanks!

Comment: You can find some RabbitMQ stats here: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/9b44a7aca551/priv/www/doc/stats.html